# confusion about static cells vs dynamic cells

Tags: ios

I'm trying to figure out how to have a few static cells in addition to dynamic cells (I think) but when I start a new Master-Detail app and switch the default Dynamic Prototypes to Static Cells, it crashes.

I think, since I'm still new at this, that I don't understand how all of the components (table views, cells, delegates) are wired.  After I switched to Static Cells I made three cells but they don't show up.  The app just crashes.

I can include code but basically, I create a new Master-Detail, switch to Static Cells, change the name of three cells and it crashes (in the main loop).

Thanks ahead for everything.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If I understand your question, this is the explanation you are looking for:

**Prototype (reusability):**

When you use ***Dynamic cells***, you use ***Prototype cells***. That means either in IB or in your code, you create an instance of `UITableViewCell`, and give it an identifier (`reuseIdentifier`). The `UITableView` uses this ***prototype*** to generate as many cells (rows) as you need. `UITableView` create (and use memory) for as many cells as it needs to fill the screen. Once some of these cells go off the screen, `UITableView` ***reuses*** them -- ***recycles*** them.

You can define more than ***one*** prototype cell in a `UITableView`. The idea is that each prototype serves a different purpose. For example, you define a prototype cell that has only one big `UILabel` and its purpose is to use static text. You define another prototype that has only one `UIImageView`. It depends on your design and how you want to display your data.

To use prototype cells, in IB, you use ***Dynamic Prototypes cells***, and set an `identifier`. Then you have to implement `UITableViewDataSource` methods, such as:

> ```
> – tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: 
> – tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
> ```

These methods are delegate methods of UITableView.

If not using IB, you would create cells in `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

> UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
>   initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString
>   *)reuseIdentifier];

**Static:**

The idea of static cells is just simplicity. You can use the prototype cells (e.g. only one prototype) and feed in a static `NSArray`, for example, as data source. To take the task of implementing `UITableViewDataSource` methods, Apple introduced static cells, where you would only use the storyboard and IB. In IB, you select the table view, and choose ***Static Cells*** instead, and type in your text, or set the image.
You don't want to make any dynamic changes to static cells later when the app is running because it is not meant to, and you would have to implement many more methods that it is not worth it. Although it not much of a work to get the `indexPath` of the selected row, but the idea is if you need to push a new view from selection of a static cell, you would use segues, instead of implementing any code.

When using static cells, you should not implement `UITableViewDataSource` method, otherwise your app crashes, and vice versa, if you do not implement `UITableViewDataSource` methods (required ones) when using prototype cells, your app crashes.

Comment: I'm going to go through that with a finetooth comb (did you write that for this?  Or did you find it somewhere?) but getting rid of the UITableViewDataSource methods did the trick (had to add "numberOfRowsInSection".

Comment: Glad that it worked. Did it just for you! though you can find more extensive explanations out there. Good luck!

Comment: One nice thing I learned from all of this is that there is extensive documentation in the Class Reference (Organizer - Documentation).  Next time I'll read all applicable Class Reference Docs before I post!

Comment: Is it possible to combine static and dynamic cells in a table view?

Comment: No, it's not. At least as far I know. Because for the part that is prototype, you need to implement the data source method, but that raises an exception for the static ones. You can't discriminate which row should call the data source, and which not + I don't think Xcode lets you choose both at the same time.