# Tableview height based on its content

Tags: uitableview

I want to create table view's that are constrained to their super view's with a top,left, and right margin, but a lessThanOrEqualTo bottom margin.  This way if the tale view's content is taller than its super view it will be constrained to the bottom margin and scroll.  But if its e.g. only 3 cells, and the cells have their own internally consistent constraints, the tableview will be e.g. 200 pts tall and their will be space between it and the super view bottom margin.  So far when trying this, if i don't specify the bottom constraint or set it as lessThanOrEqual to I see an ambiguous layout warning in the visual debugger.

Comment: Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts as it's dynamic you need to provide height for UITableView to dynamically generate row inside of it. it's not possible because you don't have access to UITableView last cell content view.

Comment: every other view works the way i want.  e.g. with a stack view i don't have to be concerned with the height.  it will grow to its content.  if i have a few labels in a vertical stack view and those labels have 2,3,4 lines of text the stack view will just grow to the proper height.  why can't table view do this?

Comment: In UITableView with dynamic cell layouts use prototype cell and each cell has it's own Identifier so we are using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:` so that we can use one cell e.g 100 times because it's dynamic. stack view is static in this content but dynamic in height or width.

so UITableView with dynamic type just don't know how many times you will reuse one cell with it's Identifier.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10965464/8918347

Comment: but at some point tableview knows right?  it reloads the data and has all it cells at that point can't you snap the height to its content?

Comment: but until that some point you need to give UITableView Height then you can change it manually in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell:` it will call when tableView will display cell then you have to calculate by yourself e.g.  if the tale view's content is taller than its super view then scroll enable or change height like so

let me know if you want to know how this will work.

Comment: i want to know lol

Comment: have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Tableview height based on its content with UITableViewAutomaticDimension**

```
    //make bottom margin constraint  @IBOutlet for tableView
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var rowCount = 3

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

**make outlet connection to a tableView bottom constraint**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }

    var height: [CGFloat] = [0]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let indexRowNo = indexPath.row

        //will give you cell height for indexPath
        let frame = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)

        //if cell height already exists in height update value else append
        if self.height.count-1 >= indexRowNo{

            height.remove(at: indexRowNo)
            height.insert(frame.size.height, at: indexRowNo)
        }else{
            height.append(frame.size.height)
        }


        if indexPath.row == (tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last)?.row {
            //remove old cell heights if now tableView has less noOfCell after reloadData
            if self.height.count >= rowCount{
                for _ in rowCount..<self.height.count{
                    self.height.removeLast()
                }
            }
        }

        // total Height for tableView
        let totalHeight: CGFloat = height.reduce(0, +)

        //e.g. - less/greater ThanOrEqualTo bottom margin  conditions
        let viewTotalHeight = self.view.frame.height - 80


        if totalHeight <= viewTotalHeight{
            let value = (self.view.frame.height) - (totalHeight + 10)
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = value
            self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }else{
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
            self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        }
    }
```